# wx xrc + aui manager

Tags: python, wxpython, xrc

Is it possible, and if so, how(links, tutorials) to use XRC to load aui-elements?

I want to create a somewhat advanced interface for a program, without wanting to do everything in-code.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

I don't think XRC supports AUI (either the C++ or the pure Python version found in wx.agw.aui). However, you should be able to mix XRC items with AUI. See http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/xrc-aui-toolbar-problem-test-attached-td2344498.html

Basically you just create the frame and other items that ARE supported in XRC and then add the AUI code on top.